# JS FileReader duplicating itself with previous values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am quite new to JS promises and while working with them I got into a problem. First, let me explain what I am trying to achieve and what is getting achieved. I was creating a function that creates a file type input element that accepts images and then listens to onchange event handler on that element. When the user selects an image I call `.then()` method to resolve a promise which uses `FileReader()` to extract base64 of the image. What happens is that when I try to add the image again using that function the older image gets added as well. This repetition keeps on happening with the amount of older images already added. This is my code so far,

```
const imageInput = document.createElement('input');
imageInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
imageInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');

imageInput.onchange = () => {
    const imageFile = imageInput.files[0];
    if (/^image\//.test(imageFile.type)) 
    {
        getBase64(imageFile).then(
            data => insertImage(data)
        );                        
    } 
    else 
    {
        console.warn('You could only upload images.');
    }
};

function clearImageInput() {
    imageInput.value = '';
}

function handleImage(){
    clearImageInput();
    imageInput.click();
}

function getBase64(file) 
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
}

function insertImage(base64_string)
{
    // This function basically inserts the image into the Quill Editor.
    // But if I insert an Image A first and then try to insert Image B
    // Meaning basically I only called handleImage() twice but
    // It will insert in this pattern:
    // -> Image A
    // -> Image A + Image B

    // Follwing click handler is was being executed more than once
    // I added .unbind() before .click() to resolve the issue

    $(".some-btn").click(function(){
        var altText = "My Text";
        var titleText = "My Text";
        if(altText != "" && titleText != "")
        {
            let range = quill.getSelection(true);
            quill.insertText(range.index, '\n', Quill.sources.USER);
            quill.insertEmbed(range.index + 1, 'image', {
                alt: altText,
                url: baseString,
                title: titleText
            }, Quill.sources.USER);
            quill.setSelection(range.index + 2, Quill.sources.SILENT);
         }
         else
         {
             alert("Input the details!");
         }
     });
}
```

The code above is basically is used to overwrite the default methods of the WYSIWYG HTML editor. So when I click on the add image button on the editor I call `handleImage()` function which then processes image upload. Now, this scenario is actually happening: When I add an **image a** the function works perfectly fine and gives me the base64 of that image which in turn I insert into the editor. But when I try to add **image b** First the function will give base64 of **image a** then it'll give the base64 of **image b**. The function basically duplicates itself. And this problem keeps on duplicating when I add more images. As far as the calling of this code is concerned it is called as follows:

```
var toolbarModule = quill.getModule('toolbar');
toolbarModule.addHandler('image', handleImage);
```

In above example I am adding an event handler to Quill which is an online JS HTML editor.

Comment: Hi Gingitsune, there is not enough info here to solve your problem. you need to show the code of you calling your handle image button, as well as what you mean when you say "the image gets duplicated with previous values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem: Basically we should only create the input once and add onchange event once, then just reuse it. then, everytime `handleImage` is called, we first call `clearInput()` before opening the file dialog for new selection. In my opinion, instead of this method of having the input only exist in dom but not in the document, you should instead have an input hidden inside of your button (by giving input zero opacity and absolute position with 100% width and height inside of the button, everytime button is clicked file input will trigger. if you want i can demonstrate to you what a file upload using this common pattern looks like.

```
const imageInput = document.createElement('input');
imageInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
imageInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
imageInput.id = "img-inp-tmp";
// Listen upload local image and save to server
imageInput.onchange = () => {
  const imageFile = imageInput.files[0];
  if (/^image\//.test(imageFile.type)) 
  {
    getBase64(imageFile).then(
      data => insertImage(data)
    );                        
  } 
  else 
  {
    console.warn('You could only upload images.');
  }
};

function clearInput() {
  imageInput.value = '';// by setting value to empty, we clear the files!
}

function handleImage(){
  clearInput();
  imageInput.click();
}

function getBase64(file) 
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}

function insertImage(base64_string)
{
  // This function gets called multiple times based on how much handleImage() was called
}
```

Comment: So I tried your method, but the image is still getting duplicated with the previous one. I think the problem is with the promise resolution. In my opinion, the promise keeps its previous values when called and in turn causes this issue. I maybe wrong here.

Comment: @Gingitsune show your calling code. what do you mean "the image is still getting duplicated with the previous one". also show your code for `insertImage`

Comment: @Gingitsune thanks, i will take a look and see if i can reproduce the issue and find a solution

Comment: So I found the solution. Basically, there was no issue with the main logic. Both of our logic is correct. The problem was basically a click event handler inside `insertImage()` function. The event handler was multiplying itself. I added `unbind()` before it which resolved the issue.